# Best Plugins for Complex Index of Resources

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-recommendation, advanced-taxonomy-queries

The title might seem a little redundant, but I was wondering if anyone has any recommendations on creating a complex relational database using Custom Post Types (CPTs). I know (theoretically) how to code this, but want to know if there already exists a plugin, or series of plugins, so that I don't have to spend too much time creating a whole bunch of SQL tables and PHP code. I work part-time and am knowledgeable enough that this would take dozens of hours, and I don't think that the nonprofit I work for would be able to budget that much time.

I work for a literary organization, and I'm trying to create a publicly available index of resources. So you would have CPTs like "Literary People", "Literary Organizations", and "Publications". If you click on one of the publications, it would have the title, some background information, and then it would list things like the publishing house, the editor, the founder, etc. So if you click on the publishing house, it takes you to a CPT "Literary Organization" with a Custom Taxonomy "Org Type" of "Publisher" with their name. If you click on the editor, it would lead you to their "Literary People" page and have their background information as well as all of the organizations and publications that they are affiliated with.

The plugin CPT-Onomies does a good job of this, except that I can't create a CPT called "Literary People" and then have separate fields called "Editor", "Owner", "Writer", etc. I can simply connect the person; I can't connect the person and add a title.

Comment: You might want to look at Elastic Search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CPT-onamies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cpt-onomies/) is a great plugin for this and would some extra custom fields not work?

What I would do is use [Advanced custom fields](http://advancedcustomfields.com) and load different fields based on the location rule. Like using the `taxonomy term` rule or you could go really specific with the `post taxonomy` and load fields when a certain `Literary People` is selected.

As a example:

Load fields when the post has the taxonomy `Literary People`

- Editor
- Owner
- Writer

Load fields when the post has the term `J. K. Rowling`

- Checkbox really famous for writing Harry Potter

This last field would only show when a post has the term `J. K. Rowling` from the taxonomy `Literary People`

More info on [Location rules for ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/custom-location-rules/).

Hope it helps,